# How to get user feed in instagram?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

The Instagram API has become increasingly restrictive lately. I wonder if it's possible to fetch an user's feed to show in my app.

The user would connect via instagram in my app, giving permission to show their feed.

Is this possible in 2018?

Answer (score 0):

Get access token
http://instagramwordpress.rafsegat.com/docs/get-access-token/

you need to change the access token and the UserId in the below code.then it will work

```html
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="instafeed.js-master/instafeed.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <div class="container">
        <div id="instafeed"></div>  
    </div>
```

```
if ($instafeed.length) {
            var feed = new Instafeed({
                get: 'user',
                limit: 8,
                userId: userId,
                accessToken: accessToken,
                template: '<a target="_blank" href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" /><div class="instagram-post-stats"><div class="likes">{{likes}}</div><div class="comments">{{comments}}</div></div><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>',
                resolution: 'standard_resolution',
                sortBy: 'most-recent',
            });
        }
            feed.run();
```